# What is this method doing to this list?

Tags: python

Sorry for the title I have no idea how to phrase what the code I found is doing.

I have this code I am trying to understand and I ran into this

```
data = file_data[sent:sent + to_send]
```

What does this do to the file_data list, and what is the proper name for this type of method?

Comment: It's slicing the list and it's not a method

Comment: It's called a `slice`. It is slicing the list between the first and second values, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4][1:1+2] == [1, 2, 3, 4][1:3] == [2, 3]` There is an optional 3rd value to slice that can define a `step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually `slicing` your `file_data` list.  let's see it with an example,

```
>>> file_data = list(range(10))
>>> file_data
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> sent =2 
>>> to_send = 3
>>> data = file_data[sent:sent + to_send] # file_data[2 : 2+3] => file_data[2 : 5]
>>> data
[2, 3, 4]
```

So, you will get a new list starting from the 2nd index till the (5-1)th -> 4th index.